# MySQL DB Causing Spike-up on Windows Server CPU

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, windows-server, magento

This is a Magento application connected to MySQL Db. When I ran `show engine innodb status\G`I get a list of `TRANSACTIONS`and it looks like some of them are pending and others are in a `DEADLOCK`and it doesn't matter if I kill them, they keep coming back. What can I do to prevent that? Help!
Here's the log:

```
---TRANSACTION 284071526856416, not started estimating records in index range
mysql tables in use 10, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 284071526852056, not started estimating records in index range
mysql tables in use 10, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 284071526902632, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 284071526853800, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 284071526845080, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 39922654, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1654, OS thread handle 6724, query id 46131 localhost ::1 root updating
UPDATE `log_visitor` SET `session_id` = 'imtbh6fl9rldnoi44vjnmepf70', `first_visit_at` = '2020-01-14 19:49:19', `last_visit_at` = '2020-01-14 19:49:27', `last_url_id` = '0', `store_id` = '1' WHERE (visitor_id='1763150')
---TRANSACTION 39922653, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1669, OS thread handle 5184, query id 46128 localhost ::1 root updating
UPDATE `log_visitor` SET `session_id` = 'fvobv8l301a79ece0006vot6a5', `first_visit_at` = '2020-01-14 19:49:23', `last_visit_at` = '2020-01-14 19:49:27', `last_url_id` = '0', `store_id` = '1' WHERE (visitor_id='1763153')
---TRANSACTION 39922646, ACTIVE 2 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1623, OS thread handle 5048, query id 46079 localhost ::1 root updating
UPDATE `core_session` SET `session_expires` = '1579034965', `session_data` = '_secure_cookie_check|s:32:\"919e25a2e43969e5d6bfbede7bb4e55d\";core|a:5:{s:23:\"_session_validator_data\";a:4:{s:11:\"remote_addr\";s:14:\"159.138.159.72\";s:8:\"http_via\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"http_x_forwarded_for\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"http_user_agent\";s:166:\"Mozilla/5.0(Linux;Android 5.1.1;OPPO A33 Build/LMY47V;wv) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,link Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 Mb2345Browser/9.0\";}s:12:\"visitor_data\";a:15:{s:0:\"\";N;s:11:\"server_addr\";s:4:\"\n\0\";s:11:\"remote_addr\";s:
---TRANSACTION 39922645, ACTIVE 2 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1624, OS thread handle 6820, query id 46078 localhost ::1 root updating
UPDATE `core_session` SET `session_expires` = '1579034965', `session_data` = '_secure_cookie_check|s:32:\"d1e4c0600c606a203e398f2844d33ada\";core|a:5:{s:23:\"_session_validator_data\";a:4:{s:11:\"remote_addr\";s:15:\"159.138.153.198\";s:8:\"http_via\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"http_x_forwarded_for\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"http_user_agent\";s:166:\"Mozilla/5.0(Linux;Android 5.1.1;OPPO A33 Build/LMY47V;wv) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,link Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 Mb2345Browser/9.0\";}s:12:\"visitor_data\";a:15:{s:0:\"\";N;s:11:\"server_addr\";s:4:\"\n\0\";s:11:\"remote_addr\";s
```

Comment: Are you using `BEGIN...COMMIT`?  `autocommit=ON`?  `OFF`?  What kind of control does `magento` give you over defining and bounding transactions?

Comment: Does the UPDATE  `core_session` have a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE log_visitor;   and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE core_session;

Answer (score 0):

If not impacting business, have you tried to kill the connection app-side?

We had an issue with locked/active sessions from an app to a MSSQL DB, however the only way we could bypass was to break the active connection from the app to the DB via failover. That was only because it shifted resources from node 1 to node 2. We attempted to kill the connection via MSSQL queries but couldn't get it to stop that way, so failover ended up being the solution for us.

Note: I am still new to DBA, but figured it's worth a try to share what I've experienced in my short time in this role.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like something else is trying to connect to the DB, but I still can find what is it. When you said failover, do you mean to disconnect or change the connection string configuration from the app to the mysql?

Comment: Failing over for that sounds a bit drastic to me! @Jacman p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Failover was to move from one db node to another. However what Verace said is correct and that's rather drastic so I wouldn't recommend it as the end all be all solution. When we were working the active connection issue, it was in tandem with a storage issue, and that's what fixed it for us. 

What you may want to do is look at the app server and check for active connections from it to the DB server. If you see any active connections that match the error log from MySQL, then kill those on the app server and see if your MySQL instance is happier.

Comment: @jacman This url may be of value to you in dealing with deadlocks and how to minimize their frequency.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html